# Can resharper notify me when suppressed warnings are not needed?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

For example if I get a warning that my method can be made static, and I suppress the warning just for that method. Later I make a code change that prevents the method from being static. The comment that suppresses the warning is now pointless. Is there a way to be notified that the comment isn't actually suppressing any active warnings/errors?